# CSS @font-face Only Loading 2 Font-Weights

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I'm trying to use the following CSS that adds a font family with six different font-weights.

```css
@font-face { font-family: myFont; font-weight: Thin; src: url('../fonts/myFont-Thin.ttf'); }
@font-face { font-family: myFont; font-weight: Light; src: url('../fonts/myFont-Light.ttf'); }
@font-face { font-family: myFont; font-weight: Medium; src: url('../fonts/myFont-Medium.ttf'); }
@font-face { font-family: myFont; font-weight: Regular; src: url('../fonts/myFont-Regular.ttf'); }
@font-face { font-family: myFont; font-weight: Bold; src: url('../fonts/myFont-Bold.ttf'); }
@font-face { font-family: myFont; font-weight: Black; src: url('../fonts/myFont-Black.ttf'); }

.myClass{
    font-family: myFont, sans-serif;
    font-weight: Medium;
}
```

When I try to use the class `myClass`, it uses the myFont-Bold.ttf with a font-weight of 400 instead of using the myFont-Medium.ttf with a font-weight of 400. Inside of the developer tools, I'm able to see it's only loaded two font-weights of my font: Bold and Black. When I delete the line for the black font-weight, it then loads in Regular and Bold. Why is it only loading two font-weights instead of all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using invalid `font-weight` keywords. (See MDN: [font-weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight))

Style names like "light" or "medium" are commonly used in desktop environments  (e.g using a graphic application) – these style names are actually stored in a font file (at least in formats like truetype/ttf).

However, browsers can't use these internally stored style names and need an explicit style/weight mapping like so:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myFont;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("../fonts/myFont-Thin.ttf") format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: myFont;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("../fonts/myFont-Light.ttf") format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: myFont;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("../fonts/myFont-Medium.ttf") format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: myFont;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("../fonts/myFont-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: myFont;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("../fonts/myFont-Bold.ttf") format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: myFont;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("../fonts/myFont-Black.ttf") format('truetype');
}

body {
  font-family: myFont, sans-serif;
}

.thin {
  font-weight: 100;
}

.medium {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.black {
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

I strongly recommend using **numeric font-weight values** for better compatibility as well as specifying the **format** like `format('truetype')`

You should also include a `font-style` to map normal and italic styles.